# How to clean css and js in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created my website from html template via visual code studio. Now website speed is very low, because there are so much unused css and js remaining from template. How can I clean these? What is the easiest and most practical method?

Comment: without looking at code its impossible to suggest an answer here. Try asking a more specific question otherwise you wont find much in terms of help.

Comment: You can create a blank template..

Comment: [CSS](https://css-tricks.com/how-do-you-remove-unused-css-from-a-site/)

|

[JS (with webpack)](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/)

Answer (score 1):

You should minify your css and js files.
you have to compress all your images which are very high in size.
After doing these things your site speed will get improved.
there are so many online tools which easily minify your css, js files.